# C# DataGridView изменяет обьект в другой форме

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using(var form = new EditContactWindow()) {
    form.FirstNameLabeledBox.TextBox.Text = ((Contact)this.ContactsGrid.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).FirstName;
    form.MiddleNameLabeledBox.TextBox.Text = ((Contact)this.ContactsGrid.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).MiddleName;
    form.LastNameLabeledBox.TextBox.Text = ((Contact)this.ContactsGrid.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).LastName;
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
    BindingList<PhoneNumber> list = new BindingList<PhoneNumber>(((Contact)this.ContactsGrid.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).PhoneNumbers);
    source.DataSource = list;
    MessageBox.Show(((Contact)this.ContactsGrid.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).PhoneNumbers.Count.ToString());
    form.NumbersGrid.DataSource = source;
    form.SaveButton.Enabled = true;
    form.ShowDialog();
    MessageBox.Show(((Contact)this.ContactsGrid.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).PhoneNumbers.Count.ToString());
}
```

Почему всегда изменяется (если изменять)

> ((Contact)this.ContactsGrid.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem).PhoneNumbers

и list а не только list

Comment: Это происходит потому что вы используете одну и ту же привязку к одним и тем же данным. Используйте разные привязки, к другой копии данных.

Comment: @4per как? я делал копии

Comment: @MikeWaters вы делаете копии ссылок, а надо делать копии данных, если вы, конечно, желаете "отвязать" эту форму от основной формы. Копии данных нужно делать через цикл foreach создавая в нем новые экземпляры нужных вам классов и наполнять ими ваши коллекции, кот. будут источниками данных для этой новой формы.